# Check if input field empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have used the code below elsewhere in my site and it works.  For the life of me I can't understand why it doesn't work here.  PROBLEM: keeps throwing alert message.

My HTML:

```
<form action="processForms.php" method="post" id="joinCommitteeForm" class="headForm shadow">
                <div class="outerBlue" style="background:white">
                    <button type="button" id="cancelForm" class="button" title="Cancel">X</button>
                <br><br>
                <h3>Get involved&mdash;join a committee!</h3>

                <?php if(empty($name)||empty($email)||empty($workPhone)){
                echo "<p class='red'>All fields must be filled out...</p><br><br>";
                }?>
                <label for="name" style="width:40px">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
                <label for="email" style="width:40px" class="clear">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br>
                <label for="phone" style="width:40px;margin-bottom:20px" class="clear">Phone</label><input type="text" name="dayPhone" id="phone"/>
                <hr>
                <p class="clear">Please select a committee from the list below</p><br><br>
                <select name="comName" id="comName" style="width:215px;margin-left:50px;float:left">
                <option value="">Select one...</option>
                <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT committeeName FROM committeeName ORDER BY committeeName");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    echo "<option value = '".$row['committeeName']."'>".$row['committeeName']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";?>
                <input type="submit" name="submitCommitteeInterest" class="button orange-button clear" value="Submit" style="margin-top:40px"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <p class="small white" style="line-height:1em;margin-top:20px">NSGP never sells or gives away your personal information</p>
            </div>
            </form>
```

My JS:

```
$("#joinCommitteeForm").submit(function() {
        if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#name").val()) === "") {
            alert('All fields are required');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where do you define `$name` and `$email`?

Comment: Why the "===" instead of standard "==" for this case?

Comment: try `if ($.trim($("#email").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#name").val()) == "")`

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion yet? And is it helping at all, or does it seem to be something else? Perhaps I could try finding another solution if this didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicate `#email` and `#name` elements in your page (may be outside the form)?

Comment: @Joeytje50...you're right. I am not defining $name/$email. I though the .val() could grab the value of an element? I have tried to ALERT the val() of $email and I get nothing. I'm thinking it would be better if I serialize() on .submit and handle any issues in PHP.  Is this a better approach?  Also any reason why `var temp = $("#email").val();` doesn't return the actual value? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect the problem is here, is that you are testing if `$name` or `$email` is empty, but since you never define them, they will always be empty, per [PHP `empty()` docs](https://www.php.net/empty): "A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals `FALSE`".

To fix that, you'll need to change your PHP if-statement to:

```
<?php if(empty($_POST['name'])||empty($_POST['email'])||empty($_POST['dayPhone'])){
  echo "<p class='red'>All fields must be filled out...</p><br><br>";
}?>
```

Also, your POST parameter `$workPhone` doesn't seem to exist in your form. I've changed it to `dayPhone` here.

The variable `$_POST` will contain all parameters in the POST request from the form that's submitted.

Comment: OP seems to have a problem _before_ submission?

Comment: @SalmanA OP seems to have a problem with the form validation. Since there's form validation *before* submission via JavaScript, and there's validation *after* submission via PHP, the problem could lie in both. It seems to me the problem is in the PHP, since I see no definition of these variables, and undefined variables will return `true` when placed inside an `empty()` call. That would be the only explanation I would have for this problem.